# AWS Cloudwatch Search Expression

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to see if the community could help me figure out if this is possible.

I'm currently working with a lot of data in Cloudwatch and after getting the search expression to work I was wondering if we could take something like:

```
[{"expression": 
    "SEARCH('{AWS/ApiGateway,ApiName} ApiName', 'Average', 300)", "id": "e2"}]
```

and use it to only return specific ApiName's.

Example being:

```
test1
test2
test3
data1
data2
data3
Fubar1
```

I ask this because with the line above it will show all those data in Cloudwatch and that's useful and great but I want to know if I can do something like.

```
[{"expression": 
    "SEARCH('{AWS/ApiGateway,ApiName} ApiName = \"test"\', 'Average', 300)", "id": "e2"}]
```

And have it return just:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

I'm reaching out because from documentation it seems like it's not possible and that if I want to do something like this I should maybe look into Log Filters potentially. Anyways thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `ApiName="test"` it will match exactly `test`, but if you remove the double quotes and do `ApiName=test` it will mach all ApiNames that contain `test`.

So your expression would be

```
[ { "expression": "SEARCH('{AWS/ApiGateway,ApiName} ApiName=test', 'Average', 300)", "id": "e2" } ]
```

See here for more examples:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/search-expression-examples.html

Comment: Well was not expecting it to be that simple but thanks for the reply that has solved a question that's been bugging me for a while. Could I ask a follow up question, using the same logic with the search expression could I also use it to narrow a data scope down. Example is we have 300+ lambdas and wanted to find out if you could have Cloudwatch only show data instances where a lambda function cold started. 

This is where we assume we would have to use a Filter Logs on Lambdas.

Comment: Can't see a way to do it with search expressions. If you have this info in the logs already, checkout Logs Insights: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html

Comment: The answer is not completely accurate. For example, ApiName=test will not matching the word "testing". The reason for this is that cloudwatch uses tokenization for CamelCase and words with non-alphanumeric delimiters. Make sure you understand how tokenization works here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/search-expression-syntax.html#search-expression-syntax-tokenization